# Error con git add remote

Tags: git, github

El problema es que intento agregar un repositorio remoto a git y al hacerlo obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El URL del repositorio es correcto.

En entornos gráficos de git, como Sublime Merge, si me deja agregar el repositorio remoto con el mismo comando.

¿Qué puede ser el error?

Comment: git add es para añadir recursos a seguimiento. git remote add es para añadir el repo remoto

Comment: Tienes invertida las palabras es `git remote add` y tu lo tienes como `git add remote`